# How to create a live link for Html?

Tags: html, github

I am trying to create a live link for my Html project in Github

I was expecting a live link but Its just opening the codes

Answer (score 0):

Do you means you wanna a link like xxx.github.io that could show your html webpage in real time?
If so, you could

1. Create a new repository, and named it as ***username**.github.io*

   Attention: **username** is your github's truly username
2. Push or upload your files to this repository and then wait for a few minutes
3. Visit your own website  ***username**.github.io*

At last, all the changes will show on this url